# ASP.NET MVC: Returning a view with querystring intact

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, query-string

I'm creating a messaging web app in ASP.NET and are having some problems when displaying an error message to the user if they go to send a message and there is something wrong.

A user can look through profiles of people and then click, 'send a message'. The following action is called (url is /message/create?to=username) and shows them a page where they can enter their message and send it:

```
public ActionResult Create(string to)
{
    ViewData["recipientUsername"] = to;

    return View();
}
```

On the page that is displayed, the username is entered in to a hidden input field. When  the user clicks 'send':

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection, string message)
{
    try
    {
        //do message stuff that errors out
    }
    catch
    {
        ModelState.AddModelErrors(message.GetRuleViolations()); //adding errors to modelstate
    }

    return View();
}
```

So now the error message is displayed to the user fine, however the url is changed in that it no longer has the querystring (/message/create). Again, this would be fine except that when the user clicks the refresh button, the page errors out as the Create action no longer has the 'to' parameter.

So I'm guessing that I need to maintain my querystring somehow. Is there any way to do this or do I need to use a different method altogether?

Comment: Since the Create method takes a `string to`, when you return the View `to` will still be set in the Url (querystring or wherever your routing rules puts it). Are you saying that once you call `return View()` the Url no longer contains "to" in the querystring?

Comment: hmm... I think you may have just answered my question. In simplifying my action above, I just added it as a parameter to the post Create action. Have updated to show actual code. I get the recipient by collection['recipientUsername']. If I change this to a parameter of the create action, will it be fixed? If so, flick up an answer and I'll mark it. (also, yes - the url no longer contains the 'to' in the querystring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are doing something like...

```
<% Html.BeginForm("Create", "Controller") { %>

<% } %>
```

As you are creating the Form's action url through routing, the existing route values will be lost in the process.  The easiest way to avoid this is by just using the parameterless version of `BeginForm`, since you are on the page you are posting to.

```
<% Html.BeginForm() { %>

<% } %>
```

This will use the current url, query string and all, as the ACTION of the form. Otherwise, you will need to pass in the route value `to` in the `BeginForm` overload.

Answer (score 1):

Recommend you take a look at the PRG pattern which will help with this.

http://devlicio.us/blogs/tim_barcz/archive/2008/08/22/prg-pattern-in-the-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx

Comment: I see it says to add error messages in TempData instead of the Modelstate. I didn't think this fits with asp.net mvc's suggested error handling.